# Migrating database connection string from appconfig.json to Environment Variable

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, environment-variables, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net 5 Web API hosted as an Azure App Service.
The app connects to a MySql database, also hosted on Azure (Azure Database for MySQL server).

Until now, I've had the connection string for the MySql database in the code's appsettings.json file.
I would like to move this to an Environment Variable. (I'm aware of Azure Key Vault, but I got a bit lost trying to figure that out, so I thought I'd try using Environment Variables instead)

For now, I am testing this locally on my development PC (Windows 10 + Visual Studio Community 2019). Once I get it working there, I will do the same on production environment.

So like I mentioned, currently the connection string to the MySql database is stored in the appsettings.json file as follows:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDataContext": "Server=abc.mysql.database.azure.com;user id=someuser@abc;Pwd=somepassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=somedatabase;TreatTinyAsBoolean=false"
  },
```

So I created a System Variable called *ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext* on my development machine.
I then deleted the above lines from appsettings.json to make sure my app is not reading from there anymore.

But now I'm a bit lost... I thought perhaps this was all I needed to do, as my Program.cs, which looks like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
   .UseNLog();
}
```

Contains the CreateDefaultBuilder() which, according to Microsoft docs, "loads app IConfiguration from environment variables". However, in my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 29))));
    ...
}
```

*Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext")* returns null.

I also tried adding the connection string as a User Variable instead of an Environment Variable, but this made no difference.

Is there something else I need to do to get this to work?
I haven't tried this in a production environment yet - I'd like to get it working on my development machine first.

Thanks

Comment: Where have you added environment variables when configuring configuration?

Comment: You could configure your connection string in azure portal, so you need just to leave empty your connection string value in appconfig.json, the connection string will be replaced 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-connection-strings

Comment: Is `Configuration` used in `Startup` injected to built manually?

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your question. So I have added an Environment Variable to Windows on my development PC (as I'd like to get it working locally first). I have also added it in Azure App Service (under Configuration -> Application settings) as for production I assume I will need it there too. I guess I'm just not sure how to read these environment variables. I kinda thought it would happen automatically.

Comment: @alessandro Thanks for the reply. Yes, I did configure my connection string in Azure Portal, by going to my App Service -> Configuration -> Application settins, and adding an application setting called ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext (just like the one I added in the Windows Environment Variables of my development PC). I then left the connection string value in my appsettings.json empty (instead of deleting it altogether as I had previously done) but still getting a null when trying to read it.

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez the default env variable prefixes are `DOTNET_` and `ASPNETCORE_`. Have you tried `DOTNET_ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext ` or `ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext ` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I did try with those two prefixes, but it made no difference. The strange thing is that replacing Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext") with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext") also returns null.

Comment: I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57713484/net-core-environment-variable-returns-null that when running the code in debug mode (as Ive been doing) it will NOT read environment variables from Windows. They have to be supplied in the Project Properties. And indeed, if I do that, I can read the environment variables using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext"), so I'm a step closer. I still however cannot read it with Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext"). But I will test by running the API with DOTNET RUN instead and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [LaunchSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lsj) to specify `ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext`.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64645",
      "sslPort": 44366
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ConnStringInEnv": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext": "Server=abc.mysql.database.azure.com;user id=someuser@abc;Pwd=somepassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=somedatabase;TreatTinyAsBoolean=false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out the only problem was that I was running the Web API in debug mode (from within Visual Studio). Once published to Azure App Service, it worked. To recap:

In Azure App Service Configuration, I added an environment variable called *ConnectionStrings__MyDataContext* with the relevant value.

In my code's *Startup.ConfigureServices()* method, I read in the environment variable, and assign it, like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<LogContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDataContext"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 29))));
```

That's it!